# Can I use phpMyAdmin or MySQL to check when a record was made or modified without a timestamp column?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, admin

**Scenario.**

Simple database which has a list of addresses

```
addressID
FirstName
LastName
City
PostCode
CountyID
ZoneID
```

The problem is that by default this table doesn't have a creation or timestamp column at the end. However I have full access to MySQL through my Nginx SSH Ubuntu 11 setup - I can also login to root phpMyAdmin.

Can I check for example when a particular entry was made, modified etc ?

Comment: You can't unless you add a column to your table that has that specific purpose.

Comment: I only could find the date of the last update of a table; which is the file-date of the *.frm files under `/var/lib/mysql/SCHEMA/TABLE.frm`…

Comment: Would that list what was updated, which record etc or would it just give a date.

Comment: So what if someone uses InnoDB without file per table turned on? Then what? In lack of appropriate term, it's dumb to check file's last update / access time for such purposes. That's why databases are called databases - they are bases of data. Unless you opt for having a field that tells you when you created something or did something to a record, then it's your own fault you haven't came up with correct data model. You **can't** have the DB automatically hold metadata about records in a table. That's db engineer's job, to set up environment for such purposes (data model).

Comment: @N.B. Who took the jam out of your donut. Mistakes happen.

Comment: @M1th - I didn't post to argue, just to clarify. You can have your donut reference back. Yes, mistakes happen and proper ways of doing things have to be written, bolded and what not so that people not as familiar with certain techniques remember the correct way.

Comment: Fair point. I will remember in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In short, no**. This is not impossible 99% of the time. Especially in the environment being MySQL. NoSQL and other services like MongoDB and other environments differ.

Run this script in phpMyAdmin for future use now (you already suggested you were going to make a stamp record).

```
ALTER  TABLE Addresses
ADD Column CreatedOrModified timestamp
NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

You can also use the NULL and also DateTime Stamp for the default values.
You can also have PHP send the Data inside the MySQL field:

```
$stamp=$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: @fancyPants Ok, so I used to SQL query to add timestamp against each record. the time is coming in 24 hours format like 2015-04-23 19:43:00 however i want it to be 12:32 am (simple 12 hours format). How do I do that?

Comment: @Faizan Use the [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.